# Create an audience for users where a specific user property is NOT set

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Our app sets a "parseid" user property when the user authenticates, and only then. In other words, if the user just installed the app and hasn't registered or signed-in yet, that firebase user property isn't yet defined.

Is there a way to create an audience that captures these non-authenticated users? When I look at the options to create a condition on that user property, I don't see anything that would be "is not set" or something equivalent. I suspect there may be a way to do something with a regexp matching any string with 1 or more character, and then targeting all users NOT in that audience, but not even sure I could validate that since Firebase doesn't show the users who matched the criteria.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To exclude users press this button to set conditions.

[image: button]